# Recovered Sender Address from Raw Transaction

Tags: php, rlp

I'm trying this code example : https://thomasclowes.com/verifying-an-ethereum-signature-on-the-server-php-2/

**Expected $recoveredSenderAddress** = 0xd5bfc359c3a377bb8afd41db8ffc8d1349718233

**Actual $recoveredSenderAddress** = 0x65f0041f24b95b4d73cb128491b592f08a432c37

Tested transaction is =>  https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xc14a23d652315c871474142745bc23268e0fac2ee9f0d56a108e208571c03a86

```
// $transactionRaw = 'f86a06843b9aca00835d161494e2f9d68bb0d2adcb0d926e93896366d0f2a4573886313030303030801ba0a267b2cd995a8475b967f688d96af1442af777c545cac8d35d08225e31167b32a066308ac688f621ad3f284a63153af7d7c711409926ac0c7e0231fdf0f005b74f';

public function recoveredSenderAddress($transactionRaw)
{
    $rlp = new RLP; // Lib Web3p\RLP\RLP (Recursive Length Prefix)
    $decodedArray = $rlp->decode('0x'.$transactionRaw);

    $rHex = $decodedArray[7]->toString('hex');
    $sHex = $decodedArray[8]->toString('hex');
    $vValue = $decodedArray[6][0];

    //"v" => 27
    //"r" => "a267b2cd995a8475b967f688d96af1442af777c545cac8d35d08225e31167b32"
    //"s" => "66308ac688f621ad3f284a63153af7d7c711409926ac0c7e0231fdf0f005b74f"

    $messageHex       = $transactionRaw;
    $messageByteArray = unpack('C*', hex2bin($messageHex));
    $messageGmp       = gmp_init("0x" . $messageHex);

    $r = $rHex;     //hex string without 0x
    $s = $sHex;     //hex string without 0x
    $v = $vValue;   //27 or 28

    //with hex2bin it gives the same byte array as the javascript
    $rByteArray = unpack('C*', hex2bin($r));
    $sByteArray = unpack('C*', hex2bin($s));

    $rGmp = gmp_init("0x" . $r);
    $sGmp = gmp_init("0x" . $s);

    $signature = array_merge($rByteArray, $sByteArray);

    $recovery = $v - 27;
    if ($recovery !== 0 && $recovery !== 1) {
        throw new Exception('Invalid signature v value');
    }

    $publicKey = Signature::recoverPublicKey($rGmp, $sGmp, $messageGmp, $recovery);

    $recoveredSenderAddress = "0x".substr(hash('sha3-256',hex2bin($publicKey['x'].$publicKey['y'])), 24);

    return $recoveredSenderAddress;
}
```

What am I doing wrong ? Thx !

Comment: I can send you a snippet to decode a transaction in `golang`, its 60 lines of code. It takes raw transaction from `stdin` and dumps all the values to stdout. You can compile it as executable and invoke from your PHP with `exec()` , or you can compile it as a php extension if you know how to write an extension.

Comment: I've to note that ethereum uses keccak256 instead of the oficial sha3, see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44742153/keccak-256-in-php.

Comment: @Nulik Thank you but I would like to do it in php. There are implementations that work in JS also like ethereumjs-tx for example but my goal is to understand the problem in this script

Comment: @Ismael thank you for your help. After some tests, and comparing step by step with the JS version that works, even before the use of sha3, the $publicKey in my script is not good.

**Actual**
49b3c834a579e4e8d03c4fe3faed5ae6f5cc8766c1de0f5091f51a5885f35356fd1000711dbfc31fb9ec01c0dadca1d9a2b89d3b92f69b63d0c7971410d0a687

**Expected**
52721ad1fcf8d852853c395e614101a11e29eb3c9e583f147b0d9cde79986b3c451abe7cc8f7aeccc16f168dbd9c48777369f395158c5d02aaea229eca5f649f

Comment: @vincentLg Your issue is because you verify the raw transaction, and you have to verify the hash of the transaction without signature (ie without r, s and v). Take a look at https://github.com/web3p/ethereum-tx/blob/master/src/Transaction.php#L338. Sorry I'd try to write an example but I'm not very good at php.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a library for that https://github.com/digitaldonkey/ecverify